# Loop for in mail with ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I've got a problem with the email sending when i used a for-loop in my email.

When I use ampscript in my email everything goes well until I use a loop, either simple or complex.

If i just put this in my ampscript: `%[ for $i = 1 to 3 do set @hi =" hello" next @i ]%` the email never sends and the status in My Tracking is Canceled.

I tried to send an email with a long ampscript of more than 50 lines and the email sent in less than a minute (without loop ofc).

do you have an idea for my email to send? (I really need to used a loop in my mail for customize the text)

Edit 26/12/2017 : The email works now for no reason. Thx for you'r investigated !

Comment: Make sure the email validates.  There should be a button in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

AMPScript blocks are bounded by `%%[` and `]%%`. You're also not referencing the variables correctly.  AMPScript variables start with an `@` symbol. Here's lookup loop example:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("lookupField") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @lookupValue = "whee" /* or a literal value */
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
    set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

    ]%%

    Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

    %%[ 
  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Reference:

- [**AMPScript Language Elements**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)

Comment: My code works perfectly in landing page but in email not. is isnt a syntax pb

Comment: Hmm. What you have above is not valid AMPScript.